# How to access elements of a custom List data type?

Tags: haskell

I created a custom List type and I'm trying to implement the zip function for it. But I cant figure it out, it always throw an error on the last line.

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a) deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)

listZip :: List a -> List a -> List a
listZip _ Empty = Empty
listZip Empty _ = Empty
listZip (Cons x1 (x2)) (Cons y1 (y2)) = Cons (Cons x1 y1) (listZip x2 y2)
```

Comment: `listZip :: List a -> List a -> List a` the return type here looks wrong: how can the result have the same type? Also, `(Cons x1 y1)` is wrong since `y1` is not a list. You might want to use standard pairs here...

Comment: when you zip 2 lists, shouldnt it return another list? and can you elaborate on the pairs?

Comment: Indeed the result should be a list, but not a list of the same type `a`. The answer below provided more details anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type looks wrong, you probably want to return a list of 2-tuples, so:

```
listZip :: List a -> List a -> List (a, a)
```

or more generic:

```
listZip :: List a -> List b -> List (a, b)
```

Then you implement this with:

```
listZip :: List a -> List b -> List (a, b)
listZip _ Empty = Empty
listZip Empty _ = Empty
listZip (Cons x1 (x2)) (Cons y1 (y2)) = Cons … (listZip x2 y2)
```

where I leave the `…` part as an exercise.